# Pick Images From Photos Android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When Pick Photo From Android it allow me choose from (Gallery, Photos, and more applications )
I want to set Photos as default, and deny user to choose.
[I use this code For Pick Multi Images](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/)
[Picture illustrating my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3w7t.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You need to include the relevant code in the post, not as an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution For Help

Change

```
var imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
```

To

```
var imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
```